# Why my requestAnimationFrame is not working?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I am trying to make the car move using JavaScript by using `requestAnimationFrame`. I have a car on the screen but the car is not moving; for some reason, my animation is not working.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
canvas.width = 200

//Draw the car on canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') // use 2d canvas context 
const car = new Car(100, 100, 30, 50)
// car.draw(ctx) // draw the car using the context

//move the car 
animate();

function animate() {
  car.update();
  car.draw(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate); // calls the animate function again and again as many times as we want
  //give illusion of the movement that we want

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: darkgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

#myCanvas {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
  class Controls {
    constructor() {
      this.forward = false
      this.left = false
      this.right = false
      this.reverse = false

      this.#addKeyboardListeners(); //# is used here because this is a private method, you can't access this from outside of the controls class
    }

    #addKeyboardListeners() {
      document.onkeydown = (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
          case "ArrowLeft":
            this.left = true
            break;
          case "ArrowRight":
            this.right = true
            break
          case "ArrowUp":
            this.forward = true
            break
          case "ArrowDown":
            this.reverse = true
            break
        }
//        console.table(this)
      }

      document.onkeyup = (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
          case "ArrowLeft":
            this.left = false
            break;
          case "ArrowRight":
            this.right = false
            break
          case "ArrowUp":
            this.forward = false
            break
          case "ArrowDown":
            this.reverse = false
            break
        }
//        console.table(this)
      }

    }
  }
</script>
<script>
  class Car {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
      this.width = width
      this.height = height

      this.controls = new Controls();
    }

    //update the position of the car according to the key pressed
    update() {
      if (this.controls.forward) {
        console.log("going up");
        this.y -= 2

      }
      if (this.controls.reverse) {
        this.y += 2

      }
    }

    //draw a static car
    draw(ctx) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(
        this.x - this.width / 2,
        this.y = this.height / 2,
        this.width,
        this.height
      );
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Your current Stack Snippet throws an error because `Car` is not defined.

Comment: @D.K please post the `Car` class also so we can test your code

Comment: @SurajRao by not working I mean the car I made in HTML AND CSS is not moving!

Comment: @IgorMoraru sure I have posted Car too!

Comment: Is `console.table(this)` printing?

Comment: Yes, I added this line in my code so that I can test if my keyboardListener is working properly! @SurajRao

Comment: It would be helpful if you would just create one runnable snippet with the needed code (not more) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `ctx.rect(
            this.x - this.width/2,
            this.y = this.height/2,
            this.width,
            this.height
        );` does this look right?

Comment: **Typo:** in your `ctx.rect()` you are assigning `this.y = this.height / 2` when you wanted `this.y - this.height / 2`. Also, you'll want to call   `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` at the beginning of your `animate`, you will also probably want to change the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` handlers to `addEventListener()`, here the next instance will overwrite these handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! I have fixed the typo and reorganised your code a bit. To stop the main document from scrolling when the car is moved up or down, use `event.preventDefault()`, which prevents the browser from receiving the arrow key press.

I have used `tabIndex` and `focus()` to give the keypresses to the canvas from the start (an element needs a tab position in order to be to be focused).

`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` clears the previous screen before the new frame is drawn to give the movement.

```js
  class Controls {
    constructor() {
      this.forward = false
      this.left = false
      this.right = false
      this.reverse = false
      this.#addKeyboardListeners();
    }

    #addKeyboardListeners() {
      document.onkeydown = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        switch (event.key) {
          case "ArrowLeft":
            this.left = true
            break;
          case "ArrowRight":
            this.right = true
            break
          case "ArrowUp":
            this.forward = true
            break
          case "ArrowDown":
            this.reverse = true
            break
        }
      }

      document.onkeyup = (event) => {
        switch (event.key) {
          case "ArrowLeft":
            this.left = false
            break;
          case "ArrowRight":
            this.right = false
            break
          case "ArrowUp":
            this.forward = false
            break
          case "ArrowDown":
            this.reverse = false
            break
        }
      }

    }
  }

  class Car {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
      this.width = width
      this.height = height
      this.controls = new Controls();
    }

animate() { 
 
      if (this.controls.forward) this.y -= 2
      if (this.controls.reverse) this.y += 2
      if (this.controls.left) this.x -= 2
      if (this.controls.right) this.x += 2

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);        
      ctx.fillRect(
        this.x - this.width / 2,
        this.y - this.height / 2,
        this.width,
        this.height
        );

    }
  }

const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
canvas.width = 200
canvas.tabIndex = 0;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') 
const car = new Car(100, 100, 30, 50)
canvas.focus()

animate();
function animate() {
  car.animate();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
  }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: darkgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

#myCanvas {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```